# react-native volume listener up down

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to control the volume up and down of react-native.
The library you used is
react-native-volume-manager
react-native-volume
react-native-keyevent
I've used my back
I don't see a listener for up and down.
Isn't there a solution?

Looking for react-native volume up down listener

Answer (score 0):

Example from docs https://github.com/hirbod/react-native-volume-manager#usage-

```js
import { VolumeManager } from 'react-native-volume-manager';

// Enable or disable the native volume toast globally (iOS, Android)
VolumeManager.showNativeVolumeUI({ enabled: true }); // default is true

// Set the volume (value between 0 and 1)
await VolumeManager.setVolume(0.5); // float value between 0 and 1

// Set volume with additional options
await VolumeManager.setVolume(0.5, {
  type: 'system', // default: "music" (Android only)
  showUI: true, // default: false (suppress native UI volume toast for iOS & Android)
  playSound: false, // default: false (Android only)
});

// Get the current volume async (type defaults to "music")
const { volume } = await VolumeManager.getVolume({ type: 'music' });

// Listen to volume changes (example)
useEffect(() => {
  const volumeListener = VolumeManager.addVolumeListener((result) => {
    console.log(result.volume); // current volume as a float (0-1)

    // On Android, the result object also has the keys:
    // music, system, ring, alarm, notification
  });

  // Clean up function
  return () => {
    volumeListener.remove(); // remove listener
  };
}, []);

// With useFocusEffect from react-navigation
useFocusEffect(
  React.useCallback(() => {
    const volumeListener = VolumeManager.addVolumeListener(async (result) => {
      if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
        try {
          VolumeManager.enableInSilenceMode(true); // Enable audio in silent mode
        } catch {}
      }
    });
    return () => {
      volumeListener.remove(); // remove listener
    };
  }, [])
);
```

Comment: The result up-down key is not visible in VolumeManager.addVolumeListener.
I want to know if the up and down key is pressed